# Could not select drop down list option in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

Based on the image below the dropdown list option id is id="CountryId"
[image]

```
 Select dropdown = new Select(obj.findElement(By.id("CountryId")));
 System.out.println(dropdown + "is trigger");
 dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Malaysia");
 dropdown.selectByValue("52");
```

Based on the snippet above I am keep getting error which could not select the drop down list option

[image]

Comment: Can you share the page link?

Comment: @Prophet http://demowebshop.tricentis.com/cart

Comment: I see no dropdowns on that page...

Comment: @Prophet http://demowebshop.tricentis.com You have to add a product to cart and u will see a dropdown list option at cart page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with JS as well :

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('CountryId').selectedIndex = '52';");
```

**update 1 :**

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://demowebshop.tricentis.com/cart");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("BOOKS"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("h2.product-title a"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[id^='add-to-cart-button']"))).click(); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("shopping cart"))).click();
Select select  = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("CountryId"))));
select.selectByValue("52");
```

Comment: still not working getting session id error

Comment: Can you share the entire error stack trace ? In text format here ?

Comment: Session ID: b12dccd3-af5a-b54d-9a47-0a71d2b57631

 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)

Comment: See the above updated 1 section, it works fine on my local.

Comment: yes thanks it works i think is because i did not add the WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

Answer (score 0):

Is the page fully loaded when you try to click on that dropdown?

Is that dropdown inside another object and not accesible on its own?

One of those things are happening.

I'd start with

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(yourDriver, 10); 
WebElement select = 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(selectFinder)));
select.click();
```

If that doesn't work then the select is not accesible on its own and you need to go through its parent items on the HTML until its available. It doesnt make much sense but thats how selenium works.